# InfoPath form field text outside field border

Tags: infopath

Not sure if InfoPath issues are addressed much in this community but since it's SharePoint connected, I wanted to ask the following...

We have an InfoPath form that submits/posts to a SharePoint List. After filling out the form and submitting it, when the user reopens to review or make updates, it is noticed that the text in several fields on the form are running outside the field area or "bleeding". This issue is only occurring when "viewing" the submitted List item, not when editing or filling out the form.

Is this simply a quirk of SharePoint? Or is this situation resolvable?

Please advise... thanks... tga

Comment: Can you add any screenshot to be more specific?

Comment: Appreciate the response.... Apparently from the time I posted my query to now, SharePoint has corrected itself and the contents of the form no longer display in error as mentioned... so this issue resolved.